# implementing touches to drag various images with finger

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to be able to drag various images around using touches. So far, I'm trying to get it to work with just 1 image, but it's not working (i.e. I can't move the image with my finger). What am I doing wrong?

I have several files with the following code:

**DragView.h**

```
@interface DragView : UIImageView {
}
@end
```

**DragView.m**

```
#include "DragView.h"
    @implementation DragView

    - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)set withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        CGPoint p = [[set anyObject] locationInView:self.superview];
        self.center = p;
    }

    @end
```

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DragView.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) DragView *basketView;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
 #import "ViewController.h"

    @interface ViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    @synthesize basketView;

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        basketView = [[DragView alloc]
                      initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"basket.png"]];
        basketView.frame = CGRectMake(140, 340.2, 60, 30);
        [self.view addSubview:basketView];
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
basketView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

[Documentation says that:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> New image view objects are configured to disregard user events by default. If you want to handle events in a custom subclass of UIImageView, you must explicitly change the value of the userInteractionEnabled property to YES after initializing the object.